# What are some easy all-in-one options to play TTRPGs online with only phones?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, tool-recommendation

So, the short version of all this is that my local D&D group will no longer be able to meet in person for the foreseeable future. Some of them ***/only/*** have their smartphones to use: no tablet, no laptop, not even a chromebook.

My hope was to use roleplay.tv for this, but I (on Windows 10 with a headset but no webcam) and my partner (Android on Chrome) cannot hear each other. Discord seems like it would be able to handle everything except combat, since there isn't a way to handle live pieces on a board.

Is there an easy-to-use all-in-one website or app that I, the DM, can use to control locations on a battle map alongside sound and ambient music so that the party can follow along?

Basically, here are my team's needs:

- Cross-compatible between Android, iOS, and Windows
- Voice-chat
- Share a primary screen of content to lobby
- Lobby can select and move certain pieces of on-screen content (for battle maps)

Nice, but not necessary:

- Video-chat
- Options to play audio from site/app itself for ambiance
- Automatically set up grid spaces to easily track distances
- Can roll various dice, in multiples, without leaving site

Comment: Are they using these phones for communication as well? Meaning the app should faciltate that as well?

Comment: Ideally, here's what I need:

*Able to communicate through phone
*Able to have a shared interaction screen for a live battle map
*Able to be cross-compatible with folks on Windows, Android, and iOS
*In-site dice rolls would be cool too, but we all have dice so eh

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't do reccomendations on this part of the site, but you might try on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Zachiel We should probably remove that tool-recommendation tag - I'd assumed it was on topic but checking the questions under that tag they're all closed.

Comment: @LioElbammalf I don't know the story of the tag, you'd better discuss the opportunity of removing it in [meta] rather than here, where very few people will see it. Please note that when hovering about the tag it says "this tag exists for hystorical reasons only"

Comment: @lioelbammalf the tag exists as a warning, the except starts with "OFF TOPIC — DO NOT ASK RECOMMENDATION QUESTIONS."... It's a shame using them doesn't pop up a bigger warning.

Comment: That being said, you can always ask on [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat).